# How to build RPM from SVN?

Tags: svn, rpmbuild

I'm looking for a way to build RPM from the SVN. I know that i need to export to the source directory, but i wondered if there is any source or app i could use to do that.

In particular, i was wondering how to:

- Pass revision and version number from the SVN to the RPM.
- Deal with configuration files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [Docu: IzzySoft Release Framework : Software Release Made Easy](http://www.izzysoft.de/software/ifaqmaker.php?id=0) -- that's what I use for my projects. It pulls the code from various sources (including SVN, CVS, filesystem via `cp`), generates `.tar.gz`, `.deb`, `.rpm`, handles the changelog, uploads to the target server(s) via scp, ftp, rsync... It may require a little time for the initial setup -- but once that is done, releasing a new version of your programm is as easy as `relman MyProg 1.2.3` (where `1.2.3` is the version number to give to the release, as used for packaging). It will then ask for confirmation -- and shortly thereafter (depending on your project), all the files are on the server(s).

Comment: You're welcome! All the parts of it are documented -- but if there are questions left, just go ahead and ask.

Comment: I just notice I forgot the *disclosure:* I'm the dev of said framework, and author of the linked article. Though that might have been guessed from the name and my nick already, it's custom to explicitly state it. Better late than never ;)